# How to password restrict viewing of Chrome history?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to restrict the viewing of the history with one simple password authentication. What is the **most simple way** of doing it?

I would not like to set up multiple or indeed any chrome account. I would like to have only one history. The only needed feature is if someone would like to view the history, has to provide a password.

Thanks for your answers and tips!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this I can think of is using a Chrome plugin. A quick search brought me [Simple Startup Password](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-startup-password/ojoalkffommhmdmbohjphohoejjmgepc), which asks for a password *every time you start Chrome*. However, I could not find a history-only protection.

I hope this still fits your needs.

Comment: That is nice, however I would not like to login every time for normal browsing, only for the history.